# A Geometry Question Concerning Six Equilateral Triangles

Tags: geometry

The question is as follows:

> The figure below is built by joining six equilateral triangles ABC, ACD, CDE, DEF, EFG, and FGH, all of whose edges are 1 unit long. It is given that HIJKLMB is straight.
>
> (a) There are five triangles in the figure that are similar to CMB. List them, making sure that you match corresponding vertices.
>
> (b) Find the lengths of CM and EK.
>
> (c) List the five triangles that are similar to AMB.
>
> (d) Find the lengths of CL, HI, IJ, and JK.

[image: The figure for which this question is concentrated upon]

I believe that we need to use a concept based on similar triangles, but I am unsure as to what I should be doing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For a) I see eight  these triangles.

Comment: Yes, I see the eight similar triangles. I mainly am concerned with solving part b).

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I just see six, where are your extra two?

Comment: @Joffan $\Delta BMC\sim\Delta BMC$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg  $CMB, EKB, GIB, FIH, DKH, AMH$ are the six I see.

Comment: @Joffan Yes, you are right. I thought about them twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\Delta CMB\sim\Delta AMH$, we obtain:
$$\frac{CM}{AM}=\frac{BC}{AH}$$ or

$$\frac{CM}{AC-CM}=\frac{BC}{AH},$$
which says $$CM=\frac{1}{4}.$$

$EK=\frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry.

Now, $\Delta BLC\sim\Delta HLD.$

Thus, $$\frac{CL}{LD}=\frac{BC}{HD}$$ or
$$\frac{CL}{1-CL}=\frac{1}{2},$$
which gives $$CL=\frac{1}{3}.$$
Now, since $FI=CM=\frac{1}{4}$, by the law of cosines we obtain:
$$HI=\sqrt{1^2+\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2-2\cdot1\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{4}.$$
Also, since $FI=\frac{1}{2}$ and $AJ=\frac{1}{3}$, we obtain:
$$IJ=\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{12}$$ and since $EJ=1-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3},$ we obtain:
$$JK=\sqrt{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-2\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{6}.$$ 
Done!

Comment: Can you explain to me why you wrote the proportion $\frac{CM}{AC-CM} = \frac{BC}{AH}$?

Comment: @geo_freak I added something. See now.

Comment: I understand that part now. But, now, I am unable to understand why $\frac{CL}{1-CL}=\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @geo_freak I added again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the interesting part (to me):

[image]

$$|\overline{AP}|:|\overline{PQ}|:|\overline{QR}|:|\overline{AB}| = 3:1:2:12$$

Answer (score 1):

As $BMC\sim BKE\sim BIG$ we have 
$$CM:KE:IJ=1:2:3.$$ 
But $KE=KD=1/2$ (by symmetry), then:
$$
CM=IF={1\over4},\quad IG=AM={3\over4}.
$$
In addition, $LMC\sim BMA$ and $CL:AB=CM:AM=1:3$, whence: $CL=1/3$.

Finally: $GHI\sim FJI\sim EJK$ and we know that $FJ=CL=1/3$ and $JE=2/3$, so we have:
$$
HI:IJ:JK=3:1:2,
\quad\hbox{which entails}\quad
IJ:HK=1:6
\quad\hbox{and}\quad
IJ:HB=1:12.
$$
so that:
$$
IJ={HB\over12},\quad
JK={HB\over6},\quad
IJ={HB\over4},
$$
and we can compute $HB=\sqrt{13}$ by Pythagoras' theorem to get the required lengths.